# Why does SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, ...) hang in Windows 7 when it didn't before?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, winapi

I have some code that expands the size of the system scrollbars for an application running on a touchscreen PC.  This code was written in Delphi 7 and has been running satisfactorily for several years, but I have found that there seems to be a problem when running it on Windows 7.

The code looks like this:

```
procedure SetLargeScrollBars();
type
    // Extended NONCLIENTMETRICS structure not defined in Delphi 7's Windows.pas
    tagNONCLIENTMETRICSXA = packed record
        cbSize: UINT;
        iBorderWidth: Integer;
        iScrollWidth: Integer;
        iScrollHeight: Integer;
        iCaptionWidth: Integer;
        iCaptionHeight: Integer;
        lfCaptionFont: TLogFontA;
        iSmCaptionWidth: Integer;
        iSmCaptionHeight: Integer;
        lfSmCaptionFont: TLogFontA;
        iMenuWidth: Integer;
        iMenuHeight: Integer;
        lfMenuFont: TLogFontA;
        lfStatusFont: TLogFontA;
        lfMessageFont: TLogFontA;
        // This member not supported for Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000
        iPaddedBorderWidth: Integer;
    end;
    NONCLIENTMETRICSX = tagNONCLIENTMETRICSXA;
var
    ncm: NONCLIENTMETRICSX;
    osvi: OSVERSIONINFO;
const
    LARGE_SCROLL_DIM = 48;
begin
    // Zero the NONCLIENTMETRICS type and fill in its size
    ZeroMemory(@ncm, Sizeof(ncm));
    ncm.cbSize := SizeOf(ncm);

    // This is necessary because SystemParametersInfo works differently for 
    // Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista and after.
    ZeroMemory(@osvi, SizeOf(osvi));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(osvi);
    GetVersionEx(osvi);

    if (osvi.dwMajorVersion < 6) then
    begin
        ncm.cbSize := ncm.cbSize - SizeOf(ncm.iPaddedBorderWidth);
    end;

    // Seems to return true all the time.
    SystemParametersInfo(
        SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS,
        Sizeof(ncm),
        @ncm,
        0);

    if (ncm.iScrollWidth <> LARGE_SCROLL_DIM) then
    begin
        // Save the scrollbar width and height for restoration when the application closes.
        m_ScrollWidth := ncm.iScrollWidth;
        m_ScrollHeight := ncm.iScrollHeight;

        ncm.iScrollWidth := LARGE_SCROLL_DIM;
        ncm.iScrollHeight := LARGE_SCROLL_DIM;

        // This call never returns...
        SystemParametersInfo(
            SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS,
            Sizeof(ncm),
            @ncm,
            SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    end;
end;
```

The curious thing is that the scrollbar sizes are actually set, so it seems that SystemParametersInfo is doing what it is supposed to do, but then appears to get confused after that point.

Since there is a check in the function to see if the scrollbars are already expanded, the application runs fine the second time and thereafter (unless the scrollbars are reset by reverting the theme back to the original).

I was wondering if it could be something to do with the last parameter (fWinIni) and have tried all the various values for that including zero, but to no avail.

Perhaps Windows 7 does something different to earlier flavours of the OS after the settings have been changed? Having said that, I haven't tried it on Vista, so maybe the same thing happens there.  It could be related to the addition of iPaddedBorderWidth for Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and subsequent versions - see [NONCLIENTMETRICS Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724506%28VS.85%29.aspx)

There is a similar question on MSDN [Problem Changing size of scrollbars using SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7da5c8df-7320-4eff-bfb7-14a60b655335) regarding the same situation from a .NET perspective but no answer to it so far.

---

## Further information

I have used DebugDiag to perform a hang analysis on the application concerned, and it shows the following stack trace:

> **Function**
>   ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
>   uxtheme!Ordinal45+25d
>   uxtheme!BeginBufferedAnimation+25b
>   user32!SystemParametersInfoA+40
>   programName+13024f
>   programName+117c8d
>   programName+6ae72
>   programName+727dc
>   programName+132645
>   kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+12
>   ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+ef
>   ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+c2

So it looks as if the hang is occurring in uxtheme!Ordinal45+25d - presumably in a system call of some kind.

Comment: So your question (missing here) is something like *How to make a proper SystemParametersInfo call* ? I don't want to believe that [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would freeze the application, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @TLama - Thanks for responding - it seems I got so involved in describing the symptoms that I forgot to ask the question.  I think the implied question is _Why does SystemParametersInfo hang in Windows 7 when it didn't before?_

Comment: @MattWilling Hi Matt, did you find an answer to your problem ? I'm having the same ...

Comment: Try removing `packed` from your declaration of `tagNONCLIENTMETRICSXA`.

Comment: @TOndrej Thanks for your response, I've revisited the problem nd tried your suggestion, but to no avail, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps the problem  is caused by another window. You are calling `SystemParametersInfo` with the `SPIF_SENDCHANGE`-parameter. This causes a `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` message to be broadcasted with `SendMessage`. When there is a window that does not respond to this message, the call to `SystemParametersInfo` will hang. Please read [this entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/10/392118.aspx) of The Old New Thing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm afraid it's not the answer, as the call hangs even if I pass 0 instead of SPIF_SENDCHANGE.